# Is there any way to define allowed values in terraform?

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-redis-cache

I want to create an Azure Redis Cache and want to give options to select from different SKUs. The allowed values argument is not supported and hence i cannot mention different SKUs. Is there any way to mention it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be available in Terraform 0.13.  For your specific use case, this would look as below:

```tf
variable "sku" {
  description = "which SKU do you want (options: Basic,Standard,Premium)"
  type = "string"
  validation {
    condition     = contains(["Basic", "Standard", "Premium"], var.sku)
    error_message = "Argument 'sku' must one of 'Basic', 'Standard', or 'Premium'."
  }
}
```

- [Documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#custom-validation-rules)
- [Related issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2847)

Answer (score 1):

As you have known, the allowed values argument is not supported in terraform till now.

If you want to mention allowed values when you input the variable, you could use a variable description like this,

```
variable "SKU" {
  description = "which SKU do you want (options: Basic,Standard,Premium)"
  type = "string"
}
```

[image]

Or, as a workaround from [this issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2847#issuecomment-536218898) in Github. You could use a local map and key lookup and add a value checker.

```
variable "sku" {
  description = "which SKU do you want (options: Basic,Standard,Premium)"
  type = "string"

}

locals {
  sku_options = ["Basic","Standard","Premium" ]
 # or add this to precisely match the value that case sensitive, validate_sku = "${index(local.sku_options, var.sku)}"
}

resource "null_resource" "is_sku_name_valid" {
  count = "${contains(local.sku_options, var.sku) == true ? 0 : 1 }"

}
```

Hope this could help you.